# Heredoc php syntax error

Tags: php, string, heredoc

[Syntax error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcwLa.png)

I am getting this syntax error while using heredoc in php.

> Unexpected: << after: =

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Problem not with `<<<END_OF_BLOCK` but with `END_OF_BLOCK;` you must not use whitespaces before `END_OF_BLOCK;`.

Here example:

```
<?php
$message = 'Hello World';
$variable = <<<EOT
    echo "{$message}";
EOT;
```